# How to create an alias that can substitute arguments for C shell?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, csh

I need to use the following very often

```
diff <filename.c> standard
```

How can I have an alias (`adiff`) for it so that I would do

```
adiff filename.c
```

and it would expand to

```
diff filename.c standard
```

Comment: Aliases don't take parameters and csh doesn't have functions. You have to use a script. This is one of the [many reasons not to use csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use diff's '--to-file' option.

Try adding this line to your .cshrc:

```
alias adiff '/usr/bin/diff --to-file=standard'
```

Just tested this in Bash (different alias-syntax though) and seems to work.

Please insert the full path for the file "standard" to make sure you can call it from other directories too.

Now you should be able to use:

```
$ adiff fromfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a script and put it in your bin folder:

Read the first parameter of your script input and run `diff <param1> standard`

Comment: Can't I put something in `.cshrc` to this effect?

Comment: You can make an alias for diff so that typing diff at the shell will run adiff instead (alias adiff diff (not sure about the order)) where adiff is your script, but afaik, yo can't use alias directly, you will need the script.